Eckhart Young theorem proof
I found the following proof of Eckhart Young theorem (from https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~venkatg/teaching/CStheory-infoage/book-chapter-4.pdf):

Let $B$ minimize $\vert \vert \textbf{A} - \textbf{B}\vert \vert_{F}^2$ among all rank $k$ or less matrices. Let $V$ be the space spanned by the rows of $B$. The dimension of $V$ is at most $k$. Since
$B$ minimizes $\vert \vert \textbf{A} - \textbf{B}\vert \vert _{F}^2$,
it must be that each row of $B$ is the projection of the corresponding
row of $A$ onto $V$, otherwise replacing the row of $B$ with the
projection of the corresponding row of $A$ onto $V$ does not change
$V$ and hence the rank of $B$ but would reduce $\vert \vert \textbf{A} - \textbf{B}\vert \vert _{F}^2$.
Since each row of $B$ is the projection of the corresponding row of $A$, it follows that $\vert \vert \textbf{A} - \textbf{B}\vert \vert _{F}^2$ is the sum of squared
distances of rows of $A$ to $V$.
Since $A_k$ minimizes the sum of squared distance of rows of $A$ to
any $k$-dimensional subspace, from Theorem (1.1), it follows that
$\textbf{A}_{k} = \argmin_{\textrm{rank}(\textbf{B}) = k}\vert \vert \textbf{A} - \textbf{B}\vert \vert _{F}$.

I don't understand this -

Since $B$ minimizes $\vert \vert \textbf{A} - \textbf{B}\vert \vert_{F}^2$, it must be that each row of $B$ is the projection of the corresponding row of $A$ onto $V$, otherwise replacing the row of $B$
with the projection of the corresponding row of $A$ onto $V$ does not
change $V$ and hence the rank of $B$ but would reduce $\vert \vert\textbf{A} - \textbf{B}\vert \vert _{F}^2$.

Could someone please explain?
